# ispell in Emacs LaTeX mode

Tags: emacs, latex, ispell

When I run Emacs command `ispell-buffer` on an Emacs buffer which is in the LaTeX mode, ispell checks spelling also inside math expressions.

I'd very much like to disable this. Is there an easy way to do it?

I've read about detex but detex does not seem to be integrated into Emacs.

Answer (score 8):

It shouldn't do this, if you are using latexisms (eg. \[ ... \], equation environments, &c) to invoke math mode.  Check the contents of `ispell-tex-skip-alists`; cf. [section 6 of the ispell FAQ](http://www.kdstevens.com/stevens/ispell-faq.html#AMSTex) for what kind of thing should be there.

You can use $..$, $$..$$ to mark out maths using ispell-tex-skip-alists, but beware getting them out of kilter...

**Postscript**

Check also the value of the `ispell-parser` variable: this should be `'tex`, otherwise ispell will not look for $...$ and $$...$$ regions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can: install [aspell](http://aspell.net/) instead of ispell, and use flyspell with it.

Comment: He may already be doing that. The command is still called ispell in Emacs, even if it actually invokes aspell.

Comment: Further to what @Chris said, both ispell and aspell can parse Tex maths, so this possibility isn't likely to help the qner.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but I have found [Flyspell](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Manuel.Serrano/flyspell/flyspell.html), an on-the-fly spell checker, incredibly useful when editing LaTeX documents. It still spellchecks inside equations, but it is much easier to ignore a few extra red underlines than ispell's interactive commands.

Answer (score 0):

You may know this, but you can press `A` during spell checking to add a word to the buffer-local dictionary (that's capital `A`, lowercase `a` adds it to the global dictionary). It's not ideal, but this is how I usually suppress spell-checking of technical terms and variable names, etc., in my LaTeX documents.

Answer (score 0):

[This AUCTeX mailing list thread : "spell checker (ispell-buffer) complains about products in math modes"](http://www.mail-archive.com/auctex@gnu.org/msg03415.html) has some workarounds and the answer demonstrates how to use ispell-tex-skip-alists.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `ispell-skip-region-alist`. The following example is [to exclude org-mode src blocks](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/450/intelligent-spell-checking-in-org-mode):

```
(add-to-list 'ispell-skip-region-alist '("#\\+begin_src". "#\\+end_src"))
```